# $C[0,1]$ and $C^1[0,1]$ continuous bijections in either direction

Tags: general-topology, analysis, derivatives, continuity, metric-spaces

I am trying to find two non homeomorphic topologies with continuous bijections in both directions. I know there are solutions for this online, but I would much rather someone tell me whether I'm thinking along the right lines to solve this well known problem. Please do not post spoilers.

Consider $C[0,1]$ and $C^1[0,1]$ with $f(0)=0$ and the uniform norm. $C^1$ denotes the continuously differentiable functions. $C^1$ is not complete but $C$ is so they are not homeomorphic.
I think that the maps $F[f]=\frac{d}{dx}f$ and $G[f]=\int_0^xf$ are bijections in either direction and $F[G[f]]=f$ so one of them must not be continuous. This is a shame, I'm considering modifying $F$, for instance $F[f]=\frac{d}{dx} (xf)$, maybe that smoothes things out. If I change to another norm I know (Sobolev norm maybe), I lose the nice guarantee that they are nonhomeomorphic. Am I wasting my time or is this going somewhere?

Comment: Your map $F$ is not a bijection because all constant functions get mapped to the zero function.

Comment: "_C^1 is not complete but C is so they are not homeomorphic_" This is not true: for example, $\mathbb{R}$ is complete and it is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$, which is incomplete. Try proving directly whether $F,G$ are continuous or not, you are on the right track

Comment: @BenS. $f(0)=0$ so all constant functions are identically $0$

Comment: Your maps are **linear** which is much more restrictive than your problem calls for.  Solving this question with **linear** continuous bijections is much harder than merely solving it with continuous bijections.

Comment: @GEdgar I'm surprised, it seems very natural to use differentiation and integration here

Answer (score 1):

$F$ is not continous to see that take a sequence $$f_n (t) =\frac{x^{n^2}}{n}$$ we have $$||f_n -0||_{\infty} \to 0$$ but $$||F(f_n ) - F(0) ||_{\infty} =\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1} |nx^{n^2 -1} | = n\to \infty $$
so $F$ is not continous at zer0.